# The loss value does not decrease

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I am implementing a simple feedforward neural network with Pytorch and the loss function does not seem to decrease. Because of some other tests I have done, the problem seems to be in the computations I do to compute *pred*, since if I slightly change the network so that it spits out a 2-dimensional vector for each entry and save it as pred, everything works perfectly.

Do you see the problem in defining pred here? Thanks

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch import nn

dt = 0.1

class Neural_Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Neural_Network, self).__init__()
    
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(2,300)
        self.nl = nn.Tanh()
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(300,1)
    
    
    def forward(self, X):
        z = self.l1(X)
        z = self.nl(z)
        o = self.l2(z)
        return o



N = 1000
X = torch.rand(N,2,requires_grad=True)
y = torch.rand(N,1)
NN = Neural_Network()

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(NN.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

epochs = 200

for i in range(epochs):  # trains the NN 1,000 times

    HH = torch.mean(NN(X))
    gradH =  torch.autograd.grad(HH, X)[0]
    XH= torch.cat((gradH[:,1].unsqueeze(0),-gradH[:,0].unsqueeze(0)),dim=0).t()
    pred = X + dt*XH

    #Optimize and improve the weights
    loss = criterion(pred, y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


    print (" Loss: ", loss.detach().numpy())  # mean sum squared loss
```

P.S. With these X and y the loss is not expected to go to zero, I have added them here like them just for simplicity. I will apply this architecture to data points which are expected to satisfy this model. However I am just interested in seeing the loss decreasing.

---

My aim is to approximate with a neural network the Hamiltonian of a vector field where only some trajectory is known. For example only the updates `x(t)\rightarrow x(t+\Delta t)` for some choice of points. So the vector `X` contains the points `x(t)`, while `y` contains the $x(t+\Delta t)$. My network above approximates in a simple way the Hamiltonian function `H(x)` and in order to optimize it I need to find the trajectories associated to this Hamiltonian.

In particular `XH` aims to be the Hamiltonian vector field associated to the approximated Hamiltonian. The time update `pred = X + dt*XH` is simply one step of forward Euler.

However, my main issue here can be abstracted in: how can I involve the gradient of a network with respect to its inputs in the loss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the gradient flow graph *for `NN`* is destroyed with the `gradH` step. (check `HH.grad_fn` vs `gradH.grad_fn` )

So your `pred` tensor (and subsequent loss) does not contain the necessary gradient flow through the `NN` network.

The `loss` contains gradient flow for the input `X`, but not for the `NN.parameters()`.  Because the optimizer only take a `step()` over those`NN.parameters()`, the network `NN` is not being updated, and since `X` is neither being updated, loss does not change.

You can check how the loss is sending it's gradients backward by checking `loss.grad_fn` after `loss.backward()`
and here's a neat function (found on Stackoverflow) to check it:

```
def getBack(var_grad_fn):
    print(var_grad_fn)
    for n in var_grad_fn.next_functions:
        if n[0]:
            try:
                tensor = getattr(n[0], 'variable')
                print(n[0])
                print('Tensor with grad found:', tensor)
                print(' - gradient:', tensor.grad)
                print()
            except AttributeError as e:
                getBack(n[0])
```

with `getBack(loss.grad_fn)` after `loss.backward()` to check it for yourself (maybe reduce size of batch N before though)

Edit: It works by changing `gradH = torch.autograd.grad(HH, X, create_graph=True)[0]`

Comment: Yes, thank you. It seems that the information about the NN.parameters is lost in that step.  Do you have any advice for how to solve this problem? I am new to Pytorch

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do with the gradH thing, so if you have any materials (tf code or equations) maybe I could help.

Comment: According to the [pytorch grad documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.grad), I guess using 
`gradH = torch.autograd.grad(HH, X, create_graph=True)[0]` could do the trick (depending on what you want)

Comment: I have added an update to the question where I explain what I want to do, I hope this allows you to help

Comment: It now works @DannyBoi , thank you very much for the addition of create_graph=True

Comment: glad I could be at help! You can check each operation from that gradH and forward with the neat function above so feel free to double check so that the behavior match what you desire.  (And feel free to accept the answer ;) )

Comment: Sure, I will. Thank you again :)